# Disposing an object in a thread

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable

I'm developing a C# application that gets a stream coming from a device (Kinect).

Since the framerate is too high for my CPU I have tried using threads. This seems to solve my problem. Each time a new frame is received I put in a queue and then another thread performs a dequeue and writes the frame in a file.

The code of that thread is the following:

```
private void myThread()
{
    writer1 = new VideoFileWriter();
    writer1.Open(outputFile1, 320, 240, 10, VideoCodec.WMV2);

    while (!queue.IsEmpty || !streamClosed)
    {
        ColorImageFrame item = null;

        if (!queue.IsEmpty && queue.TryDequeue(out item))
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                Bitmap result = new Bitmap(320, 240);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(ImageToBitmap(item), 0, 0, 320, 240);
                    writer1.WriteVideoFrame(result);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Queue size: "+queue.Count);
        }

        try
        {
            item.Dispose();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        if (queue.IsEmpty)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    writer1.Close();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

This seems to work well, but sometime I receive an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I think that I'm wrong in disposing the objects that are used in my thread.

Can someone help me to find these errors?

Comment: How many items could be added to the queue in the 2 seconds that you sleep for when it's empty? (I think you should be using a `BlockingCollection` rather than a queue for this...)

Comment: 20 items in 2 seconds. Cause I'm getting one frame over three frames received. I'm using `ConcurrentQueue<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Well the OutOfMemoryException is thrown when the runtime cannot allocate memory for you objects, which is kinda obvious.

Make sure your Big objects do not live long and that you dispose of them quickly.

You're VideoFileWriter objects lives for as long as their are items in the queue, how about you initialize it and dispose it in your loop so it wont take much memory?

Answer (score -1):

The Bitmap should be disposed. You're disposing the Graphics object which is good but the bitmaps will take up a lot of memory especially in loops/timer events. Then try a GC.Collect() and it will clear up anything else.

Comment: The whole point of disposable objects is that they are holding onto memory that the Garbage Collector *can't* dispose of.